# How to remove radio button while exporting to Excel using Display Tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

I want to export the table which is displayed using display tag on the jsp page.
But when I export it, it exports radio button with the table

Below is the snippet of the display tag

```
<display:table requestURI="CustListReportDetails.do" name="sessionScope.SESSION_CUST" id="formtable" pagesize="100" style="width:100%; border:0; cellspacing:0; cellpadding:10; align:center;" export="true">

    <display:table requestURI="CustListReportDetails.do" name="sessionScope.SESSION_CUST" id="formtable" pagesize="100" style="width:100%; border:0; cellspacing:0; cellpadding:10; align:center;" export="true">
    <display:column title="" style="width:10px">
        <input type="radio" name="recordIdentifier" value="${formtable.customerId}" onclick="javascript:setRoleCode('${formtable.customerId}');"/>
    </display:column>
    <display:column property="name" title="Name" /> 
    <display:column property="contactPerson" title="Contact Person" />              
    <display:column property="gender" title="Gender" /> 
    <display:column property="dob" title="Date Of Birth" /> 

    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="Customer_reportExcel.xls"  />  
</display:table>
```

The desired xsl file should not have radio button in it.

Comment: I was frustrated by the same problem, so I moved on to [this dataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/). It uses the normal html table format and has endless features. Also it does not reloads the page on sorting,paging etc. Give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved
In the display column tag containing radio button,I have placed media ="html" and now it doesn't export radio button in the excel sheet

code changed in the above snippet::

```
display:column title="" style="width:10px" **media="html"**
```